# Git Bash for windows - No such file or directory

Tags: git, git-bash

I am running a very simple script to pull multiple repositories stored in a text file. This was running fine before updating Git. Now I get a 'No such file or directory' error for each repository. If I hardcode the directory into the script it runs fine.

Here is the script:

```
filename="../Repositories/all.txt"
echo "Starting list"
printf "\n"

filelines=`cat $filename`
for line in $filelines ; do
    if
        [[ $line != !* ]];
    then
        printf "\n"
        echo $line
        repopath=${line:19}
        echo $repopath
        fullpath=/c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/$repopath
        echo $fullpath
        #cd /c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core
        cd $fullpath
        git pull
    fi
done
```

Here is the output when running bash -x pullallrepos.sh

```
+ for line in '$filelines'
 != !* ]].GeoInnovation.AddressProcessing.Core
+ printf '\n'

+ echo $'Tamu.GeoInnovation.AddressProcessing.Core\r'
Tamu.GeoInnovation.AddressProcessing.Core
+ repopath=$'AddressProcessing.Core\r'
+ echo $'AddressProcessing.Core\r'
AddressProcessing.Core
+ fullpath=$'/c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core\r'
+ echo $'/c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core\r'
/c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core
+ cd $'/c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core\r'
: No such file or directoryd: /c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core
+ git pull
Updating 4ad72a9..0c00ac0
```

If I hardcode the path here:

```
cd /c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core
#cd $fullpath
```

It runs fine:

```
+ echo $'Tamu.GeoInnovation.AddressProcessing.Core\r'
Tamu.GeoInnovation.AddressProcessing.Core
+ repopath=$'AddressProcessing.Core\r'
+ echo $'AddressProcessing.Core\r'
AddressProcessing.Core
+ fullpath=$'/c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core\r'
+ echo $'/c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core\r'
/c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core
+ cd /c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.Core
+ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

I feel like I am missing something really simple but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: See the `\r` there? The value (and most lines of the script) has a DOS line ending character at the end.

Comment: But nothing has changed in this script since before the Git update. That being said, what would be the solution?

Comment: Remove the DOS line endings, I guess; your text editor probably has an option for this (Save as... and look for an encoding or maybe character set option).

Comment: I've tried every encoding method possible in saving the .sh file, Ansi, UTF-8, etc.. they all result with the -x output adding /r to the end of the most statements. I also downloaded the original untouched version from our repository that worked prior to updating Git and get same results.

Comment: All of those are line ending agnostic. Try to find an editor which gives you control over the line-ending regime *and* the encoding (though many conflate them, offering e.g. a separate entry for UTF-8 with Unix line terminators) or a Windows port of `dos2unix` (sic). If you have `tr`, it's `tr -d '\015' <file >fixed`

Comment: I tried save the file as Unix/OSX with UTF-8 using notepad++, and also ran dos2unix conversion on the file.. all wish same results. When I run the script with cygwin it doesn't show the dos line endings: `pullallrepos.sh: line 23: cd: /c/DevSource/Tamu/GeoInnovation/AddressProcessing.: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Mark me down as an idiot. The .sh file was not the problem. The current.txt file that it pulled the repositories names from was the problem. Somewhere along the way someone apparently saved it in the incorrect format. Thank you for all the help, at least I learned a few things along the way that will undoubtedly prove useful in the future. :)